# How to access model in constants.php in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to access a function on application/config/constants.php, which is written in one of my CodeIgniter model. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Please show us some examples so we don't need to guess what you're actually asking.

Comment: No, it isn't easily done. The constants file is used way before the controller is created and you cannot "load" any other libraries (including models) until that happens. You could probably find a hack but it's not recommended. Your best solution might be to use a "hook", either a post_controller_constructor or post-controller. [Using Hooks Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Thank you but I have not too much to tell you. I want to access model in constant file that's it.

Comment: @DFriend Thank you, I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to change a constant with a model function or any function for that matter. Constants are meant to be static and strict definitions. Like application paths, version numbers, .etc.

> They are similar to a variable except that they can never be changed.

If you wish to have a variable that is a `superglobal` but needs to be dynamic in some respect you can create a `/application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

     public $someglobalvar;

     public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->model('somemodel');
          $this->someglobalvar = $this->somemodel->get_var();
     }

}
```

and have your controllers extend it instead of `CI_Controller`

(application/controllers/Some_controller.php)

```
class Some_controller extends MY_Controller {

     public function index() {

          var_dump($this->someglobalvar); 

     }

}
```